# Uniformity of prime number in arithmetic progression without logarithm integral

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

There is a vast amount of information on prime number distribution over arithmetic progressions, from Siegel-Walfisz theorem to Brun-Titchmarsh theorem.  They all state $\pi(x;q,a) \sim \frac{x}{\phi(q)\log(x)}$ under certain conditions, some times the next expression is found:  $\pi(x;q,a) = (1+ o_q(1)) \frac{x}{\phi(q)\log(x)}$.

My question is which part of the error term $o_q(1)$ is related to the actual uniformity of prime number distributed across arithmetic progressions and which is due to approximation by the $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ rather than the actual number of primes ($\pi(x)$).

In other words, what is the error term and what is the valid interval for the next expression: $\pi(x;q,a) = \frac{\pi(x)}{\phi(q)}$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. For a fixed $q,a, \gcd(q,a)=1$ as $x \to \infty$ :  $\pi(x;q,a) = \frac{x}{\phi(q) \log x} (1+o(1)) = \frac{\text{Li}(x)}{\phi(q)} (1+o(1))$ so the $o$ term can be made uniform for finitely many $q,a$. If you want a version with effective constants, see [Iwaniec & Kowalski](https://www.google.fr/search?q=iwaniec+kowalski+analytic+number+theory+pdf)

Comment: Thanks for comment and reference. For a fixed x, and any q,a, gcd(q,a) = 1 and $q<\sqrt{x}$  then $\pi(x; q,a) \approx \frac{\pi(x)}{\phi(q)}$ I wonder which is the error term in this case. Bare in mind we are using the exact number of primes ($\pi(x)$) rather than an approximation.

Comment: Do you understand what I wrote ? For a fixed $a,q$ : [$|\pi(x;q,a) - \frac{1}{\phi(q)} \text{Li}(x)| < C x e^{-b (\log x)^{d} }$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). See Iwaniec if you want explicit constants in term of $a,q$.

Comment: I believe I understand it, but my question holds what would be the bound for $|\pi(x; q,a) - \frac{\pi(x)}{\phi(x)}|$, could  $Cx e^{-b(\log{x})^d}$ improved somehow since we are using the actual value of primes lower than x, rather than $Li(x)$ ?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The bound we can prove for $|\pi(x; q,a) - \frac{\pi(x)}{\phi(q)}|, |\frac{\pi(x)}{\phi(q)}-\frac{\text{Li}(x)}{\phi(q)}|,|\pi(x;q,a)-\frac{\text{Li}(x)}{\phi(q)}|$ are exactly the same.

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: And be aware that $\frac{x}{\log x}- \text{Li}(x)= \mathcal{O}(\frac{x}{\log^2 x})$ but not better. If you don't like $\text{Li}(x)$ replace it by $\sum_{n= 2}^x \frac{1}{\log n}$ which is a $\mathcal{O}(\log x)$ approximation.